# Anything wrong with this code, in terms of the scope and copying of variables?

Tags: c++

I just made the function below

```
static int sumRange(int from, const int& to);

int Utility::sumRange(int from, const int& to)
{
    int sum = 0;
    while (from < to)
    {
    sum =+ from;
    ++from;
    }
    return sum;
}
int sum = Utility::sumRange(5,10);
```

Some questions:

I thought that maybe because within sumRange I returned the local variable sum that this might be bad because it was deleted at the end of the function and returned to the calling function. But it seems that these variables have different addresses. Have I got this wrong, does c++ make a copy of the variable in this case?

Is it ok that I'm modifying the variable from? I'm figuring that a copy is made and I'm ok to modify this, unlike 'to' where I'm passing by reference to avoid an unnecessary copy and making const to prevent editing.

Comment: BTW "passing by reference to avoid an unnecessary copy" is actually slowing your program down.  `to` is an `int`.  Copying an `int` is faster than using a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that maybe because within sumRange I returned the local variable sum that this might be bad

It's completely safe. On the other hand, trying to return a reference or a pointer to a local variable would be a problem.

> Is it ok that I'm modifying the variable from? I'm figuring that a copy is made and I'm ok to modify this

Yes, it's ok. A copy is made indeed.

---

But!

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
sum =+ from;
```

It means `sum = +from;`, which is same as `sum = from;`.

You probably want:

```
sum += from;
```

Comment: Amazing how the brain can flip characters around to show you the pattern you expceted.